# React native use vector icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, native

Im having trouble using icons from react-native-vector-icons package.

Here is how i import:

```
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import FoundationIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/Foundation';
```

Here is how i use:

```
<BottomNavigation
              labelColor="white"
              rippleColor="white"
              style={{ height: 56, elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
              onTabChange={(newTabIndex) => {return} }
              >
                <Tab
                barBackgroundColor="#37474F"
                label="Movies & TV"
                icon={<MaterialIcon size={24} color="white" name="tv" />}
                />
                <Tab
                barBackgroundColor="#00796B"
                label="Music"
                icon={<FoundationIcon size={24} color="white" name="music" />}
                />
                <Tab
                barBackgroundColor="#5D4037"
                label="Books"
                icon={<FoundationIcon size={24} color="white" name="books" />}
                />
            </BottomNavigation>
```

Behaviour is: icons are displaying, but the wrong icons. Material displays as japanese symbol, Foundation as a square with an X in the middle.

How to correctly import and use those icons?

Answer (score 1):

in my projects I'm using the import as:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
```

So try just import as:

```
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import FoundationIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';
```

Sorry, can't comment 'cause of rep, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to manualy link dependencies and rebuild project.